# Keycloak Java admin client returns 400 Error on triggering verification email

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using keycloak server version 8.0.1 and keycloak java admin client version 8.0.1 on spring boot 2.2, (with webflux and netty instead of tomcat, if that sort of info helps). 
After creating a user, when I try sending the verification email using "executeActionsEmail" method provided by the admin client, I get

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:219) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
```

**My Code**

```
//Keycloak Admin Client Bean
 @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloak(){
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(keycloakConfigs.getAUTH_SERVER_URL())
                .realm(keycloakConfigs.getREALM())
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientId(keycloakConfigs.getCLIENT_ID())
                .clientSecret(keycloakConfigs.getCLIENT_SECRET()).build();
    }
```

```
//Method Triggering email ('id' variable refers to successfully created user Id (UUID , not username or email ) in keycloak)

 @Override
    public void sendVerificationEmail(String id){
        log.debug("Sending email verification for id {}",id);
            List<String> actions=Arrays.asList(keycloakConfigs.getEMAIL_ACTIONS().split(","));
            keycloakAdminClient
                    .realm(keycloakConfigs.getREALM())
                    .users()
                    .get(id)
                    .executeActionsEmail(keycloakConfigs.getCLIENT_ID()
                            ,keycloakConfigs.getEMAIL_REDIRECT_URI(),actions);
    }
```

**Dependencies on my pom file ** [Just the relevant part, not entire structured pom ofc]

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <keycloak.version>8.0.1</keycloak.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.9.1.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**FULL STACK TRACE**

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:219)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEntityExtractorFactory.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.executeActionsEmail(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.profile.service.impl.KeycloakIdentityImpl.sendVerificationEmail(KeycloakIdentityImpl.java:43)
    at com.mycompany.profile.web.ProfileController.post(ProfileController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2267)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2075)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1949)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:191)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4095)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2267)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2075)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1949)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:145)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4110)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:228)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:170)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: Either catch the error and try to print the cause message or use a HTTP client tool such as Postman in order to try to reproduce your request to the server and have more details about it. Anyway, HTTP error 400 means probably you're missing a parameter in your request or you have an incorrect one.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Realm and client ID worked out for user creation provided by keycloak. "id" is valid. And 'actions' list is ["VERIFY_EMAIL","UPDATE_PASSWORD"].
Passing client_id and redirect_uri is not mandatory and not passing them also results in the same error.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I caught the exception and printed the stack trace. Didn't find any thing like missing data or incorrect data in the trace. I will put the full stack trace any way...

Comment: I would try to have a look to the server side logs, at least if you have access

Comment: nothing on keycloak server logs. It looks like the validation is failing at the admin client's code itself. Worst part is, I can't find the implementation of 'UserResource' interface that has executeActionEmail method in it!

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UserResource.java#L750
there are a few conditions which can possible throw an error 400 - hard to tell what exactly causes your error

Comment: @Evil_skunk That helped! I am now able to send emails with actions only. My users were not enabled, so it was failing. However the error message is not reflecting on client side.

 I'll check for redirect url validations and update my results.

Comment: @chirag-c Have you checked with redirect url? I am facing same issue with redirect url but it is working fine for actions only.

Comment: @Brijesh your redirect URL should be added in the valid redirect urls on keycloak client that you are using for calling keycloak APIs.
Add the exact redirect urls at both ends(in the keycloak admin console and the code where you are triggering the email from)