# keycloak executeActionsEmail method call throws HTTP 400 Bad Request with redirectURI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, resteasy

There is HTTP 400 Bad Request when calling executeActionsEmail with parameter clientId, redirectUri and actions but working fine with actions parameter and actions,lifespan.

```
UserRepresentation userrep = getUserRepresentation(email);
String userId = userrep.getId();
UserResource urs = usersRessource.get(userId);
urs.executeActionsEmail(Arrays.asList("UPDATE_PASSWORD", "VERIFY_EMAIL", "UPDATE_PROFILE"));
```

Above code is working fine, but when I am passing parameter clientId,redirectUri and actions it is throwing exception.

```
UserRepresentation userrep = getUserRepresentation(email);
String userId = userrep.getId();
UserResource urs = usersRessource.get(userId);
urs.executeActionsEmail("myclientid","http://localhost:8080/team/",Arrays.asList("UPDATE_PASSWORD", "VERIFY_EMAIL", "UPDATE_PROFILE"));
```

Above code throws exception

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:219) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.DefaultEntityExtractorFactory$3.extractEntity(DefaultEntityExtractorFactory.java:50) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-3.9.1.Final.jar:3.9.1.Final]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.executeActionsEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Spring boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

keycloak-admin-client

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there something wrong with 2nd fraction of code?
In below the question exception were there for all the scenario but in my case exception throws when I am passing clientId and redirectUri.

[Keycloak Java admin client returns 400 Error on triggering verification email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596001/keycloak-java-admin-client-returns-400-error-on-triggering-verification-email)

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: Issue has been resolved, clientId was incorrect.